# Why buildozer failed command "buildozer android debug"?

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

***I tried to deploy my snake kivy game via buildozer. But I only recieve this error:***

## Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain clean_builds --color=always --storage-dir="/home/xeonxeon/kivy_examples/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug

***I googled this problem and tried to run this command buildozer android clean.
But then I have this error:***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/xeonxeon/kivy_examples/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pythonforandroid.pythonpackage import get_dep_names_of_package
  File "/home/xeonxeon/kivy_examples/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/pythonpackage.py", line 50, in <module>
    import toml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toml'
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain clean_builds --color=always --storage-dir="/home/xeonxeon/kivy_examples/graphs/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     WSL_DISTRO_NAME = 'Ubuntu'
#     NAME = 'XEON'
#     PWD = '/home/xeonxeon/kivy_examples/graphs'
#     LOGNAME = 'xeonxeon'
#     HOME = '/home/xeonxeon'
#     LANG = 'C.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'xeonxeon'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     WSLENV = ''
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = ('/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_2004.4.4.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files (x86)/ATI Technologies/ATI.ACE/Core-Static:/mnt/c/Program Files '
 '(x86)/NVIDIA '
 'Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/php:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Users/XEON/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe:/mnt/c/Users/XEON/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/XEON/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/:/mnt/c/Users/XEON/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/XEON/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/:/mnt/c/Users/XEON/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/e/Tools/PyCharm '
 'Community Edition 2021.3.2/bin:/snap/bin')
#     HOSTTYPE = 'x86_64'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/xeonxeon'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

***I also tried to find out if I already have toml package. And I have this:***

```
sudo python3 -m pip install toml
Requirement already satisfied: toml in /root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.10.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't install python packages in your OS's root directory. Python don't have the required permissions to search for packages in OS's root directory.

Remove `sudo` and run the same command as belows.

`python3 -m pip install toml`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you need to update "toml"?
Try to run this:
`python3 -m pip install --user --update toml`